# Perl - parse file - write out to two different files

Tags: perl, file, parsing

I have written a Perl script to parse through a file, scrub it, and put it in a new file.  Was using test data that I was originally given to work with, but now I've gotten all the actual data and it turns out there are a good deal of records I will NOT want in the newly scrubbed file (mainly because too many of the fields in those records are empty).

So I now need to check if a particular field in a record is empty and if so, write it out to an "error" file and not write it out to the scrubbed data file.  Below is my script (and before people bring it up, I do not have the Text::CSV module nor will I ever have it available)

NOTE - until I tried putting the IF/ELSE statement in there, the code was working with the data I had prior to being given the actual data with these problem records.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl/

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use Time::Piece;

my $filename = 'uncleanData.csv';

open my $FH, $filename
  or die "Could not read from $filename <$!>, program halting.";

# Read the header line.
chomp(my $line = <$FH>);
my @fields = split(/,/, $line);
print Dumper(@fields), $/;

my @data;
# Read the lines one by one.
while($line = <$FH>) {

    chomp($line);
```

Here is the new IF statement I put in with the code below the ELSE having not changed from my prior working script -

```
# Check if the storeNbr field is empty. If so, write record to error file.
    if (!length $fields[28]) {
        open ( my $ERR_FH, '>', "errorFiles.csv" ) or die $!;
        print $ERR_FH join(',', @$_), $/ for @data;
        close $ERR_FH;
        }

    else

        {

# Scrub data of characters that cause scripting problems down the line.
    $line =~ s/[\'\\]/ /g;

# split the fields, concatenate fields 28-30, and add the
# concatenated field to the beginning of each line in the file

    my @fields = split(/,/, $line);
    unshift @fields, join '_', @fields[28..30];

# Format the DATE fields for MySQL
    $_ = join '-', (split /\//)[2,0,1] for @fields[10,14,24,26];

# Scrub colons from the data
    $line =~ s/:/ /g;

# If Spectro_Model is "UNKNOWN", change
    if($fields[22] eq "UNKNOWN"){
        $_ = 'UNKNOW' for $fields[22];
        }

# If tran_date is blank, insert 0000-00-00
    if(!length $fields[10]){
        $_ = '0000-00-00' for $fields[10];
        }

# If init_tran_date is blank, insert 0000-00-00
    if(!length $fields[14]){
        $_ = '0000-00-00' for $fields[14];
        }

# If update_tran_date is blank, insert 0000-00-00
    if(!length $fields[24]){
        $_ = '0000-00-00' for $fields[24];
        }

# If cancel_date is blank, insert 0000-00-00
    if(!length $fields[26]){
        $_ = '0000-00-00' for $fields[26];
        }

# Format the PROD_NBR field by deleting any leading zeros before decimals.
    $fields[12] =~ s/^\s*0\././;

# put the records back
    push @data, \@fields;
}
}

close $FH;

print "Unsorted:\n", Dumper(@data); #, $/;

#Sort the clean files on Primary Key, initTranDate, updateTranDate, and updateTranTime
@data = sort {
    $a->[0] cmp $b->[0] ||
    $a->[14] cmp $b->[14] ||
    $a->[26] cmp $b->[26] ||
    $a->[27] cmp $b-> [27]
} @data;

#open my $OFH, '>', '/swpkg/shared/batch_processing/mistints/parsedMistints.csv';
open my $OFH, '>', '/swpkg/shared/batch_processing/mistints/cleaned1502.csv';
print $OFH join(',', @$_), $/ for @data;
close $OFH;

exit;
```

I'm guessing my problem is where I am putting the closing brace } for the ELSE part of the statement.  Here are some sample records from the file with the last file being one of the "problem" records -

```
650096571,1,1,used as store paint,14,IFC 8012NP,Standalone-9,3596,56,1/31/2015,80813,A97W01251,,1/16/2015,0.25,0.25,,SW,CUSTOM MATCH,TRUE,O,xts,,,,,,,1568,61006,1,FALSE
650368376,1,3,Tinted Wrong Color,16,IFC 8012NP,01DX8015206,,6,1/31/2015,160720,A87W01151,MATCH,1/31/2015,1,1,ENG,CUST,CUSTOM MATCH,TRUE,O,Ci52,,,,,,,1584,137252,1,FALSE
650175433,3,1,not tinted - e.w.,16,COROB MODULA HF,Standalone-7,,2,1/31/2015,95555,B20W02651,,1/29/2015,3,3,,COMP,CUSTOM MATCH,TRUE,P,xts,,,,,,,1627,68092,5,FALSE
650187016,2,1,checked out under cash ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

When I run this script, it's still processing the "error records" and throwing up all kinds of "unitialized value" warnings.

Answer (score 0):

`Text::CSV` is useful if you need to handle quotes or embedded linefeeds. `Text::ParseWords` can do as a substitute instead if you need that capability.

But as long as you don't have quoting to worry about, `split` works just fine.

You can do something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings; 

open ( my $normal_fh, '>', "output.txt" ) or die $!;
open ( my $err_fh, '>', "errors.txt" ) or die $!;

while ( <> ) {
    if ( ( split /,/ ) [27] =~ /\w/ ) { 
        select $normal_fh;
    }
    else { 
        select $err_fh; 
    }
    print;
}
```

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for - if that $fields[28] is blank, then the record needs to be written to an error file and NOT parsed and then read the next record.  I think I'm running into problems with where to place my { and } for the ELSE part of my code.

Comment: I edited my original post to include all my current code and some sample records, if that helps.